# Animate object along path and deform accordingly

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I'm trying to animate an object across a bezier curve using path constraint but, even though the orientation of the object changes correctly, its shape doesn't change. I'd like it to "deform" according to the path... Does anyone know how can I accomplish this? I'm using a cylinder but I wanna be able to use any object with any shape.

Here's the effect I want to create:

[image]

Ref: https://www.behance.net/gallery/49401667/Twisted-letters-2

Comment: Perhaps the [Curve modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) is more appropriate if you would like to deform your object.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on it, please? I'm also posting a picture of the sort of thing I wanna do... For this picture there's not a single element being extruded along a curve, cause of the tip of the pencil, so that's why I wonder if a whole object, which is not just a tube or an extruded single shape can be twisted like that...

Comment: Certenly, make sure to post all the information needed for your particular case (e.g. multiple objects, parents....) because at the moment I can't tell you much more from what is shown in the linked manual.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Curve Modifier**

As stated in the [Blender reference manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) about the modifier:

> The **Curve Modifier** provides a simple but efficient method of **deforming
>   a mesh along a curve object**.

If you are working with a single object, make sure to fill the **Deformation Axis** field of the modifier with the correct value (X in my case, the object has no trasfomation) and to give your deformed object and path enough subdivions:

[image]

Then, you just have to animate the position of your object along the picked axis (X in this case) and optionally the rotation along the same axis to match the motion of the pencil shown in your example.

In my test file a took advantage of the keyframe modifier called **Generator** to set up a linear function for both:

[image]