# Curve deform - Follow along a path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

Whilst searching for a solution I stumbled upon [Animate object along path and deform accordingly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75215/animate-object-along-path-and-deform-accordingly?newreg=936ce530d70e43ee8c53dca5990f9a1f)

I am creating a logo for a new software project I am working on, the finished logo will have two dolphins either side of a infinity loop, I want these dolphins to be correctly deformed along the curve.
I will also create an animated 'loading indicator' with the dolphin moving arrond the loop.

I have downloaded a [Dolphin from TurboSquid](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-lwo-mode-dolphin-boned/332975) and getting it to follow the path is no problem, but I am having trouble with the curve deform.
It's difficault tweaking the Origin to be just right, I want the dolphin to be exactly along the path, but it is going all over the place.

[image]

The curve is not quite 2D:

[image]

On the Curve Modifer, deformation axis is set the X.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a better technique? Any pointers to tutorals?

Thanks. :-)

**Update**

Thanks guys for all your help.
I have had a little play arround with armatures and control objects, I have made a lot of progress but as you can see I have two issues:

1. The first bone (Bone02 in .blend file) seems to be stuck in position (it does have tracking constraint).
2. The mid-section (Bone05) is rotated causing the body twist.

[image]

(I have also updated the repo)

Comment: could you please share your file? (Simplify your dolphin if you don't want anyone to steal it)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks - I create a little [GitHub repo with the files](https://github.com/LukeTOBrien/dolphin-infinity) - One with armature, I don't know if that would be better - I have also just seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXheGvyEz3A&t=1221s&ab_channel=bugzilla2001) which maybe could help me

Comment: I thought you didn't have any armature and that you wanted to apply a simple curve modifier on an object. With an armature the solution would be different. Please tell me if the simple curve modifier could satisfy you?

Comment: if you want to use armature you might have your answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-like-train-on-a-track-snake

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an armature, follow the Batfinger's tuto [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-like-train-on-a-track-snake).

If you want to use a simple *Curve* modifier, you need to make sure that the position of your object on the curve. What you should do is:

- Choose a vertex in your curve, where your animation is supposed to begin.
- Make it the curve's origin.
- Make it the curve’s first point. To do so, enable the *Bsurfaces* addon, select the vertex, in the *Tools* panel > *Tools* > *Bsurfaces* > click *Set First Points*.
- Now put your dolphin object at the exact same point.
- Move it on the right axis so that it follows the curve.